# Running multiple background tasks in a WPF applicatiion - UI update stalling

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have tried so many variants of this code. I'm receiving the same issue no matter what. The UI updating starts fine and then stalls until the entire process is complete. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**The scenario**

In a WPF application we will be calling the same API thousands of times with different parameters passed. We need to collect all the responses and do something.

**Sample code**

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
{
   Task t = SampleTask(new SampleTaskParameterCollection { TaskId = i, Locker = locker, MinSleep = minSleep, MaxSleep = maxSleep });
   tasks.Add(t);
}

Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

```
private void SampleTask(SampleTaskParameterCollection parameters)
{
   int sleepTime = rnd.Next(parameters.MinSleep, parameters.MaxSleep);
   Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);

   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
   {
      lock (parameters.Locker)
      {
         ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1;
         LogTextbox.Text = LogTextbox.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Task " + parameters.TaskId + " slept for " + sleepTime + "ms and has now completed.";
      }
      LogTextbox.ScrollToEnd();

      if (ProgressBar1.Maximum == ProgressBar1.Value)
      {
         RunSlowButton.IsEnabled = true;
         RunFastButton.IsEnabled = true;
         ProgressBar1.Value = 0;
      }
   }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send);
}
```

The current repo is located on [GitHub](https://github.com/cfelstead/DispatcherTestingApp). Look at the SimpleWindow.

Comment: Probably what's happening is that the amount of time it takes to add the text to the text box and scroll it to the end is longer than the amount of time between updates, which causes everything to grind to a halt. You may need to update the UI less frequently. Also, DO NOT CREATE THOUSANDS OF TASKS! That's sure to break everything.

Comment: This code and the code from your repo did not compile. You cannot use **new** with a method

Comment: @SirRufo the code compiles and runs fine

Comment: The code you posted here can't compile -  if `SampleTask` is a method, then `new SampleTask(...)` cannot compile.

Comment: Then you are using not C# - this code is not valid C# code. Period.

Comment: @MatthewWatson In the actual application, I batch the tasks into smaller amounts and wait for each batch to complete before moving on. However, the same issue applies. Perhaps I am just updating too frequently.

Is there an approach you would suggest? I need performance and running in sync is too slow.

Comment: @ChrisFelstead Your code - we can see - is not too slow, it is not compiling => not running at all.

Comment: I don't know what to say other than it is running and compiling fine. I have checked the github is in sync and it is. I have cloned the repo fresh and run that.

Comment: Can you pause the debugger during the hang and post the callstack? That way we can tell what is blocking the UI thread. Btw, `Task.WhenAll(tasks);` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks @usr I have paused the application during the running to confirm the processes were still happening in the background. I'll get the call stack now.

Comment: @ChrisFelstead At this point my VS shows an error https://github.com/cfelstead/DispatcherTestingApp/blob/master/WpfDispatcherTest/SimpleWindow.xaml.cs#L95 *Type or Namespace "SampleTask" not found*

Comment: `new SampleTask(...` indicates that `SampleTask` is a class, and `private void SampleTask(...` indicates that it's a method. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create thousands of tasks - this will cause immense performance problems.

Instead, use something like `Parallel.For()` to limit the number of tasks that run simultaneously; for example:

```
Parallel.For(1,
    iterations + 1,
    (index) =>
    {
        SampleTask(new SampleTaskParameterCollection { TaskId = index, Locker = locker, MinSleep = minSleep, MaxSleep = maxSleep });
    });
```

Also if the UI updates take longer than the interval between the calls to `BeginInvoke()` then the invokes will begin to be queued up and things will get nasty.

To solve that, you could use a counter in your SampleTask() to only actually update the UI once every N calls (with a suitable value for N).

However, note that to avoid threading issues you'd have to use `Interlocked.Increment()` (or some other lock) when incrementing and checking the value of the counter. You'd also have to ensure that you updated the UI one last time when all the work is done.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I did use Parallel.For in another attempt. I think you are correct about simply sending too many UI updates. I'll work around that issue.